# MySQL .NET connector throwing "System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'System.Security.Permissions"

Tags: c#, exception, mysql-connector

I was going to try and learn a little bit of SQL and C# so I installed MySQL including the .NET connector, installed Visual Studio 2019, created a new project, referenced the MySQL.Data.dll and pretty much copied the example code from https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-sql-command.html so now I have this:

```
using System;
using System.Data;

using MySql.Data;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
namespace MySQLTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string connStr = "server=localhost;user=root;database=world;port=3306;password=masterkey";
            MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr);
            Console.WriteLine("Connecting to MySQL...");
            conn.Open(); //EXCEPTION THROWN HERE

            string sql = "SELECT Name, HeadOfState FROM Country WHERE Continent='Oceania'";
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);
            MySqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(rdr[0] + " -- " + rdr[1]);
            }
            rdr.Close();

            conn.Close();
            Console.WriteLine("Done.");
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately this code throws the following exception:

```
"System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'System.Security.Permissions, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'"
```

On the conn.Open(); line.

I really have absolutely no clue how to fix it as I don't really know anything about C# (I have some experience in Java).

Could it be I have somehow botched the installation of Visual Studio and now some components are missing? I will appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [IO.FileNotFoundException in MySql.Data.dll: Can't load System.Security.Permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48602743/io-filenotfoundexception-in-mysql-data-dll-cant-load-system-security-permissio) and [System.Security.Permissions missing when invoking JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T> in .NET Core 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48766856/system-security-permissions-missing-when-invoking-jsonconvert-deserializeobject)

Comment: @OlivierRogier Oh god it actually did!! I ran the "Install-Package MySql.Data -Version 8.0.10-rc" from the nuget console and now the code runs and returns the data from the database! Thank you so much, I swear I spent like two hours looking for a solution yesterday and couldn't find anything...

Comment: On another note though, the MySQL.Data that I referenced in the project was version 8.0.24 so why did I have to install the 8.0.10? What did that command do exactly? I'd like to understand what I actually did here.